# I need to always logout of my application when my test fails or an exception occurs. How should i do it?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, testng

I have a test case as below:

```
@Test
public void checkSomething()
{
//line1
//line2
//line3
//line4[Exception occurs here]
//line5
//line6
//line7 homepage.Logout();
}
```

Now if an exception occurs in line4 for example, then my application will never logout[line7]. This will cause my further test cases to fail since they will not be able to login since user session will be active.
How do i make it possible that logout always happen when a test fails prematurely?

I tried putting the logout logic in @AfterMethod. It works fine but is that the best practice to write test code in a configuration method like @AfterMethod?

Comment: With Java use 'try catch finally' and place the logout in the finally clause,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html  While using an @After method will work it is subverting its real purpose, the scope of its operation should be limited to setting up and tearing down services and resources associated with the test suite not the SUT, e.g. WebDriver or an ExpectedData source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting logout in `@AfterMethod` would be fine but make sure you are doing this in efficient way.

- check for logout if only test failed
- avoid using try catch because it waits for given time(ImplicitWait) to check element present and then goes in catch block instead use List

refer below code using `@AfterMethod`

```
 @AfterMethod 
 public void screenShot(ITestResult result){
       if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus()){
            List<WebElement> username = driver.findElement(By.locator); // element which displays if user is logged in
            if(!username.isEmpty())
                // steps to logout will go here
            }
       }
  }
```

Another Alternative is you can go with TestNG Listener. implement `ITestListener` in a class and override `onTestFailure` method as below

```
@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
      if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus()){
            List<WebElement> username = driver.findElement(By.locator); // element which displays if user is logged in
            if(!username.isEmpty())
                // steps to logout will go here
            }
       }
}
```

add below tag in testng.xml

```
<listeners>
   <listener class-name="com.pack.listeners.TestListener"/> // your created class name with package which implemented ITestListener
</listeners>
```

Comment: If i go with using test listener, should my class which contains my test case extend the class which implements the ITestListener interface and then override its onTestFailure method? That sounds good. This is what you are saying right?

Comment: @Rajan, No you should create a separate class and implement `ITestListener` in that class which will ask to override all unimplemented method and you have to do that additionally you have write the  logout code in `onTestFailure` method. and finally add that class in listener as shown in answer

Comment: @Rajan, Refer this blog https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/how-to-take-screenshot-for-only-failed-tests-using-webdriver

Comment: I get your point. So basically in the class where i will implement the iTestListener interface and define all its methods like onTestFailure etc. there i will have to create an object of my HomePage class which has the logout function and i will call this function from inside of onTestFailure method. And ofcourse i will add this class in the testng.xml as a listener. Right?

Comment: @Rajan, yup and inside `if(ITestResult.FAILURE==result.getStatus()){` this

Answer (score 0):

I work in C#, but the concept is most likely the same across all languages. In my case, I use a so-called "TearDown" tag in my base class to mark one method which should always run after a test. All the tests inherit this method from the base class and are handled accordingly. For the past years, this has worked out well, and to my knowledge any similar concept is considered best practice.

In pseudo-code:

```
    [TearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        try
        {
            Logout();
            OtherStuffLikeClosingDriver();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex);                            // Obviously, this logging function needs to generate logs that are easily readable, based on the given exception.
            FinishTest(testInstance, testName); // Handles critical flows that should always be finished (and "should" not be able to error out)
            throw ex;                           // In my case, throwing the exception again makes sure that the exception is shown in the test output directly. This often speeds up the first diagnose of a failed test run.
        }
    }
```

Just make sure to handle exceptions and such accordingly: the logic in your @AfterMethod should not be interrupted by unexpected issues.